# Log File Sync in Oracle 12c

Tags: database, oracle, logfile, oracle12c

I am trying to implement a workload in Oracle 12c.
In the awr reports generated, the log file sync is negligible.
Any help with regards to it?

Comment: what have you done already?

Comment: I have tried with different ora parameters.
disable logging=false. Also tried changing the size of the log_buffer and enabling force logging. nothing seemed to help so far.

Comment: if the log file sync is negligible why are you trying to optimize it? instead provide a link to awr report.

Comment: i got the way out! I was using a plsql block. So,it was performing commit-write optimization. Hence it was writing to log files in batches. So, i used Commit immediate write no wait instead of only commit. it is working fine now.

Comment: Do you even understand what commit no wait does? It means it will not wait for the commit to complete. This also means that transactions might not get committed in case of failures and the client would not know about it.

Comment: Okay! I did not know that. Any other way to ensure log file sync is one of the top 5 timed events?